# Generate random access token to a post page

Tags: php, posts, database

Is their any way to generate an random access token to a post page that is available for example 10 days.

i want to url to be like this. mypage/token?=xxxxx

Comment: what is the purpose ?

Comment: i want the page only to be accessible to the user with the token

Comment: whty not using password protected of WP? then you change it each 10 days